# Python pip installation not working how to do?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I keep trying to install Pip using get-pip.py and only get the wheel file in the scripts folder. Try running "pip" in the command prompt and it just comes out with an error. Running windows 8 incase you need.
*edit* error is 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install pip on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The latest Python installers come with pip...

Comment: error is that its not recognized

Comment: Yes cricket_007. @Asuto Seven - Please download 2.7.12 version.

Comment: Just install latest python installer from python.org, and enable environment variables option during installation. it should be built-in.

Comment: @AsutoSeven what is the python version, you are using?

Comment: @be_good_do_good 2.7.12

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
python -m pip (command) (option)
```

Do not use `()`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using latest version of Python.

In computer properties, Go to Advanced System Settings -> Advanced tab -> Environmental Variables

In System variables section, there is variable called PATH. Append c:\Python27\Scripts (Note append, not replace)

Then open a new command prompt, try "pip"

Comment: how would I append it?

Comment: @AsutoSeven Double click on the PATH variable,go to the end of the Variable Value, then add ";C:\Python27\Scripts"(without double quotes) to it. click OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try navigating to ~/Python[version]/Scripts in cmd, then use **pip[version] [command] [module]** (ie. pip3 install themodulename or pip2 install themodulename)